# .NET Core Web API - Fast search

Tags: c#, .net, rest, search, full-text-search

I have a monolith API on .NET 6 and it handles tens thousands items that can be searched by many parameters. So I'm wondering how to **improve the search**. I thought about some search engines like Lucene.NET or Elasticsearch etc. but I would like to know the **best practices** for such cases.

By the way the project structure is as following:

- Monolith API on .NET 6
- Website that uses the API
- Desktop client (more than 1000 instances) that uses the API as well
- 20+ services that also interact with the API

API processes ~1k requests per minute

Comment: Do you *really* need full text search? Since the problem becomes so much simpler if you can restrict it to searching complete words, or the start of words or strings. 10k items are not *that* many, I would expect a linear search to take somewhere on the order of 100ms. But if you need to get down to sub 1ms you likely need some type search structure.

Comment: @JonasH You're right there are not so many items however the problem is every item has a lot of dependencies I have to consider in the search as well. For instance: I need to find all customers who have more than 10 orders and older 27 years old and all their orders were done from city with name that contains "york" string. So I thought it could be handled by creation of some indexes - isn't it?

Comment: That sounds like the exact use case for a regular SQL database (with indexes). With the exception of "contains 'york' string" part, due to the aforementioned difficulty  with full text search.  Specialized libraries like Lucene might help, but I have no experience with it, to cannot be of much help.